# Aligning two tables with jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, css

I have a huge gridview in a scrolling container with a fixed height. I didnt want the header to scroll so I appended the header in a different section. So basically I have two tables, one inside the holder and one outside, but I want both to have the same column dimensions so they line up.

How do I accomplish this? I'd prefer not to fixed size anything, and I definitely want to append the header column of the gridview because if I change the gridview I want the header to change. All I need is for them to line up.

Comment: Please include the relevant code.

Comment: After the data is loaded into the content table, resize each column in the header table with the corresponding content table column...

Comment: Sounds like a CSS issue more than anything, could you please include some code to backup your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this. First build your table **with** the table header. Then on document ready use jQuery to clone the table header, remove the existing header, then place the cloned copy into the other table. You may not need to set widths in this case but if you do you can get the width of the original table's columns and apply those widths to the appended table (the one with the header row).

If your content table's columns change width you'll have to get the the widths of all the columns and apply them to the corresponding table header cell.

Answer (score 1):

You can select both tables and make them equal height.

```
var height = $("#object1").outerHeight();
$("#object2").height( height );

or shorter: $("#object2").height( $("#object1").outerHeight() );
```

Where object1 is your large table's id and object2 is your small table's id.